# How to workaround occasional TypeError while using numpy.bitwise_xor with large numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

While analyzing data containing large numbers (256 bits each to be exact), I've stumbled upon a different behavior of `numpy.bitwise_xor` operation. Depending on the input integers values, the function returns a number (as expected) or a `TypeError`.

Testing the `numpy.bitwise_xor` function with two sample data:

```
-  4035225266123964411 (dec) = 0011011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011 (bin)
- 18446744073709551614 (dec) = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110 (bin)
```

If both arguments are the same (either one of the above numbers), the function returns 0 (as expected). But if I try to xor the two numbers above with each other, I get the error: `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`.

```
import numpy as np

np.bitwise_xor(4035225266123964411, 4035225266123964411)
# returns: 0
np.bitwise_xor(18446744073709551614, 18446744073709551614)
# returns: 0
np.bitwise_xor(4035225266123964411, 18446744073709551614)
# returns: TypeError
```

Why the `numpy.bitwise_xor` function reports an error with casting in one case, and has no problem with that in the other case? Do you have any suggestion how to workaround this issue and xor the large (up 256 bits) numbers in python (ideally without splitting the numbers to 32/64 bit chunks)?

Comment: Do you need to use `numpy`?  Why not plain python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless explicitly told otherwise, `numpy` uses its own datatypes to contain values upon which it's operating. `4035225266123964411` is converted to `np.int64`. `18446744073709551614` is too large to fit in the biggest native `numpy` integer type (`np.int64`) so its type is `object` (formerly `np.object`). Remember that Python integers are objects.

In the first case you have two `np.int64` values. No problem with that.

```
np.bitwise_xor(4035225266123964411, 4035225266123964411)
# np.bitwise_xor(np.int64, np.int64)
```

In the second case you have two `object` values. No problem as long as `.__xor__` is implemented for those objects - which it is for `int`.

```
np.bitwise_xor(18446744073709551614, 18446744073709551614)
# np.bitwise_xor(object, object)
```

The third case is problematic because you have two values of differing types,`np.int64` and `object`, which aren't implicitly compatible with each other.

```
np.bitwise_xor(4035225266123964411, 18446744073709551614)
# np.bitwise_xor(np.int64, object) <-- unable to safely coerce into the same type
```

You can manually coerce them to the same type by specifying the `dtype` argument.

```
np.bitwise_xor(4035225266123964411, 18446744073709551614, dtype=np.int64)
# bad; 18446744073709551614 is too large and overflows

# -- or --

np.bitwise_xor(4035225266123964411, 18446744073709551614, dtype=object)
# good; both numbers are treated as type "object" making the result
# equivalent to the native Python operation:
#    4035225266123964411 ^ 18446744073709551614
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using ^

```
result = 4035225266123964411 ^ 18446744073709551614
print(result)
```

Comment: This is using native python xor, and python ints, which can large.